# Web Deploy: issue with deploying dictionary items

Tags: serialization, web-deploy

We recently switched to `yaml serialization` format for Sitecore 9.3, and we use Web Deploy to deploy sc-items.

The fact is that for some reason, new sc-items, created from this template: `/sitecore/templates/System/Dictionary/Dictionary entry (6D1CD897-1936-4A3A-A511-289A94C2A7B1)`, after deployment do not have values in the "`Phrase [unversioned]`" field.

I mean, a new item will be created and the "`Key [shared]`" field will be populated, but not the "`Phrase`" one. At the same time, If I push items to the local environment using `TDS` (having previously removed) - everything is fine, no issues at all.

Also, I don't see any errors in logs.

Here is an example of the `dictionary-item`:

```
ID: "5f3e7cd7-70e1-4b62-9a0d-0f19b5da6c00"
Parent: "81cf659f-220f-4eb2-a776-58c9cb2a3349"
Template: "6d1cd897-1936-4a3a-a511-289a94c2a7b1"
Path: /sitecore/content/Dictionaries/Features/Test
DB: master
SharedFields:
- ID: "580c75a8-c01a-4580-83cb-987776ceb3af"
  Hint: Key
  Value: Feature.Test
Languages:
- Language: en
  Fields:
  - ID: "2ba3454a-9a9c-4cdf-a9f8-107fd484eb6e"
    Hint: Phrase
    Value: Test Phrase
  Versions:
  - Version: 1
    Fields:
    - ID: "25bed78c-4957-4165-998a-ca1b52f67497"
      Hint: __Created
      Value: 20220916T093622Z
    - ID: "52807595-0f8f-4b20-8d2a-cb71d28c6103"
      Hint: __Owner
      Value: |
        sitecore\admin
    - ID: "5dd74568-4d4b-44c1-b513-0af5f4cda34f"
      Hint: __Created by
      Value: |
        sitecore\admin
    - ID: "8cdc337e-a112-42fb-bbb4-4143751e123f"
      Hint: __Revision
      Value: "8d0dbf20-4d76-4d12-bc94-31b1979af6ae"
    - ID: "badd9cf9-53e0-4d0c-bcc0-2d784c282f6a"
      Hint: __Updated by
      Value: |
        sitecore\admin
    - ID: "d9cf14b1-fa16-4ba6-9288-e8a174d4d522"
      Hint: __Updated
      Value: 20220916T093642Z
- Language: zh
  Fields:
  - ID: "2ba3454a-9a9c-4cdf-a9f8-107fd484eb6e"
    Hint: Phrase
    Value: 在
  Versions:
  - Version: 1
    Fields:
    - ID: "25bed78c-4957-4165-998a-ca1b52f67497"
      Hint: __Created
      Value: 20220916T093814Z
    - ID: "52807595-0f8f-4b20-8d2a-cb71d28c6103"
      Hint: __Owner
      Value: |
        sitecore\admin
    - ID: "5dd74568-4d4b-44c1-b513-0af5f4cda34f"
      Hint: __Created by
      Value: |
        sitecore\admin
    - ID: "8cdc337e-a112-42fb-bbb4-4143751e123f"
      Hint: __Revision
      Value: "aa0aff5e-34ec-4722-b76c-a5e6d27b6d64"
    - ID: "badd9cf9-53e0-4d0c-bcc0-2d784c282f6a"
      Hint: __Updated by
      Value: |
        sitecore\admin
    - ID: "d9cf14b1-fa16-4ba6-9288-e8a174d4d522"
      Hint: __Updated
      Value: 20220916T093819Z
```

I tried to keep only one language - the same...

Could you please help in matter?  I would really appreciate any advice/hint.